# CosmosDB SQL API, still attempting to get list of partitions and their sizes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've seen a bunch of answers on StackOverflow stating that Microsoft's Cosmosdb simply doesn't support getting a list of partition keys. This has been bothering me as it seems like a sort of a zeroith requirement for any data store, to get a list of the logical partition names and sizes - any other data store will give you things like table sizes, and I can't believe Microsoft would leave this off.

I don't think they'd do this, so it must just not be documented (or documented well at least). In the following code:

```
var client = new DocumentClient(
                    endpoint,
                    authKey

Database db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == databaseName).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

//Sure is a lot of verbose faff.  Have to keep specifying things you've already basically specified when you initialized the client...
var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(databaseSelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == myCollectionName).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

//This yields "/$pk" in the value - so I guess there's just one path, 
//but I still have a lot of distinct values in that path.  
//I try a DocumentQuery next to drill down.
var partitionKeys = collection.PartitionKey.Paths;  

var querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT DISTINCT c.PartitionKey FROM c");
var test = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.SelfLink, querySpec);
```

when I breakpoint after this last line and look at the test object, I see it has a-k sub objects, each with an integer value.  I'm not sure what these are, but could they be partitions and sizes?  Is there a better way to pull them out?

Comment: OK, I may not be getting results back as expected - when I add .ToArray(), .ToList(), .ToDictionary() to the end of the query, I get back an exception "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'DISTINCT'", error code "SC1001".
A bunch of Google searches yields people talking on forums about aggregate queries not working on CosmosDB.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7e23ec84-a5c0-41de-95ba-aa642d37c1bb/aggregates-specifically-distinct?forum=azurecosmosdb

Comment: OK, I think I've run it to ground.  People have been asking for distinct for 4 years, pretty much since CosmosDB came out (no idea why Microsoft even released their product without the most basic functionality).  Though MS says it has support for aggregates, distinct is not among the aggregate functions for CosmosDB SQL API.  At least not currently, according to the latest documentation I can find:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query

Comment: Here's the exact header in that document for aggregates - there is no support for DISTINCT:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#Aggregates

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit of an answer, though not a full one.  Therefore, I won't mark this question answered yet.

I found this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.documentcollection.partitionkeyrangestatistics?view=azure-dotnet

Here is some modified code pulling back partitions and sizes.  It only guarantees reporting on partitions > 1GB according to the above document, though the smallest reported partition I've seen so far is 42MB:

```
var client = new DocumentClient(
                    endpoint,
                    authKey
Database db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == databaseName).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(databaseSelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == myCollectionName).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
collection = await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(
            collection.SelfLink,
            new RequestOptions { PopulatePartitionKeyRangeStatistics = true });
        Console.WriteLine(collection.PartitionKeyRangeStatistics.ToString());
```

So now all I have to do is parse the strings with the reported partition names and sizes.  I'll still have further questions to answer regarding dynamically creating new partitions in order to make a system which can properly scale while using the full provisioned RUs.

Comment: I've already come across a partition which filled up.  My plan for this will be to implement time to live for that partition - CosmosDB provides a service which gets rid of documents that have expired without taking up RU.